# How to Properly Create Notification for Firestore Collection Query?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, google-cloud-firestore

So, I successfully implement notification when a Document added in a Firestore Collection,

this is the code

```
snip>code updated below
```

It works perfectly except there is one problem,

Every time I close the App and then Re-Open it, the Notification is appearing again. is there any way to make the notification appear only once after a new document added?

---

**EDIT :** I've tried adding timestamp and `if` condition but it does not work,

```
val nVoucher = HashMap<String, Any>()
nVoucher["timestamp"] = Timestamp.now().seconds
```

**New Code**

```
db!!.collection("voucher")
            .whereGreaterThan("jumlah", 0).addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshots, e ->
        if (e != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error :" + e.message)
        }
        if (documentSnapshots != null) {

            documentSnapshots.query
            for (doc in documentSnapshots.documentChanges) {
                if (doc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                    run {
                        val nvoucher = doc.document.toObject<DetilVoucher>(DetilVoucher::class.java)
                        nvoucher.docID = doc.document.id
                        voucher!!.add(nvoucher)
                        val judul = doc.document.get("judul").toString()
                        val gambar = doc.document.get("gambar").toString()
                        val docTime = doc.document.get("timestamp")
                        val timenow = Timestamp.now().seconds
                        if (timenow == docTime) {
                        remoteViews!!.setImageViewResource(R.id.remoteview_notification_image, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                        remoteViews!!.setTextViewText(R.id.remoteview_notification_headline, "Voucher Baru")
                        remoteViews!!.setTextViewText(R.id.remoteview_notification_short_message, judul)
                        val notifID = 101
                        val channelID = "com.sample.notification"
                        val notification = Notification.Builder(context, channelID)
                                .setContentTitle("Voucher Baru")
                                .setContentText(judul)
                                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                                .setChannelId(channelID)
                                .setCustomContentView(remoteViews)
                                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                                .build()
                        val notificationTarget: NotificationTarget = NotificationTarget(
                                context,
                                R.id.remoteview_notification_image,
                                remoteViews,
                                notification,
                                notifID
                        )
                        Glide.with(this@Home.context!!.applicationContext).asBitmap().load(gambar).into(notificationTarget)

                        notificationManager!!.notify(notifID, notification)}
                        vouchaerAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }


    notificationManager = this@Home.activity!!.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    createNotificationChannel(
            "com.sample.notification",
            "Voucher Baru",
            "Voucher Promo"
    )


private fun createNotificationChannel(id: String, judul: String, detil: String) {
    val importance : Int = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
    val channel = NotificationChannel(id, judul, importance)
    channel.description = detil
    channel.enableLights(true)
    channel.lightColor = Color.RED
    channel.enableVibration(true)
    channel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
    notificationManager!!.createNotificationChannel(channel)



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the app again, you're re-attaching a listener to the collection/query. And every time you do that, `docChanges` will fire with `doc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED` for each document that exists in the collection/query.

If you don't want to take action on documents you've acted on before, you'll have to track that yourself. Typically you do this by storing some data in local storage, or in the database for the user if it needs to work across devices.

The simplest scenario is if the documents have some form of creation/modification date, because then you can just store the timestamp when you last handled the documents.

If there's no timestamp (and you can't add one), you'll have to track which documents you've processed on an individual document level. While that's definitely possible, it's a lot more house keeping, so I'd definitely try the timestamp based approach first.

---

In your updated code you're comparing the timestamp in the document to the current time, which is unlikely every to be true. You'll want something like:

```
val timestamp = getTimestampFromSharedPreferences();
val now = Timestamp.now().seconds
for (doc in documentSnapshots.documentChanges) {
    val docTimestamp = doc.document.get("timestamp")

    if (timestamp == null || timestamp < docTimestamp) {
        ...
    }    
    setTimestampToSharedPreferences(now);
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Frank van Puffelen  I tried with timestamp, but it is not working, 
please check update above,

Comment: I updated my answer to include pseudo-code of this type of processing.